# Why are we not notified about new questions when we exclude certain tags?

Tags: support, bug, tags

When viewing the PHP tag, the notification below will appear when there's a new question:

[image]

However when excluding questions in the `PHP` tag which contain certain tags (for example, the tags `joomla3.0` and `android`) by typing `[php] -[joomla3.0] -[android]` into the search bar, there is no notification (as shown in the image above) about new questions and instead, I have to refresh to see them.

Comment: It looks like I may have misread your question, so I deleted my answer. What setting do you use for hiding posts? I don't see this happen, I follow a large number of tags and ignored tags posts are part of that, but I have my 'ignored tags' setting set to *grey out* such posts.

Comment: @MartijnPieters No worries, I didn't see your answer. To hide the posts, I type `[php] -[joomla3.0] -[android]` into the search bar and it brings up all the posts in the `PHP`tag without the `joomla3.0` and `android` tags. However to see new questions, I have to manually refresh the page - this isn't the case though when I just view questions in the `PHP` tag without hiding any - a message saying 'x question with new activity' appears, as shown in my question. Let me know if you would like me to explain further. I also updated my question.

Comment: Right, search pages are not 'live'. Are you using the [new navigation feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256814/new-navigation-for-stack-overflow-is-in-alpha-testing) yet? I *think* you can use that to do more sophisticated tag options.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I haven't tried out the new navigation feature yet, no. What do you mean when you say 'search pages are not 'live''?

Comment: When you use the search box with *just tags* you get a questions page, but anything more produces a search result page (I believe). The questions page is live updating, search result pages are not.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I see where you're coming from. However, my search does only include tags. `[php] -[joomla3.0] -[android]` is what I typed into the search bar

Comment: `-` is not a tag; you are using more than just tags, you are adding operators.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ah I see. Did you say that the new navigation feature solves this issue?

Comment: I *think* it does. A quick test shows that such a search ends up in a question page with the negated tags removed, page appears to be live. Out of time to test properly though.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Great, thanks for that info.